# App with totally dark, touchscreen active, on Galaxy Tab S2?

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

I need to create an app on a tablet or smartphone that responds to touches on several areas of the screen. Sounds easy, eh? The problem is that I need to precisely control all light emitted by the device. In the primary mode, the app needs to be functional without emitting any light at all. For a traditional LCD display, this means turning off the backlight, without disabling the touchscreen.

In the past, we've accomplished this by jailbreaking old iPads and hacking a bit to turn the backlight off; however, this always makes us uncomfortable, as an inadvertent upgrade will defeat this, and my client would rather not go that route. I've tried the new iPhone X with its AMOLED display, and it is almost what we need, except for the darn silly home indicator bar, which it insists on showing whenever there is any user interaction.

From my understanding, the Galaxy Tab S2 tables use AMOLED displays, and theoretically, by setting all pixels black, we will have an active display and touchscreen without emitting any light.  My question is whether there are any gotchas, such as some system-required control (similar to the home indicator) that cannot be defeated? Is it truly possible to write an app that can set all pixels black while defining controls that are active?

For simplicity, let me describe an example - a very simple app with two large buttons.  Each button must be black, the text must be black, the border must be black, and any special visual embellishments (e.g. shadow, pressed vs. unpressed state indications, etc.) must all be black.  The buttons must also be active, in that if pressed, the app will be able to perform some actions.

Is this definitely possible?

BTW - I hope there are no other light sources on the tablet (LEDs, etc.) that would be active during operation - is that true?